# Angular 8 Reactive Form: Checkbox is not clickable

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I have a nested Formgroup with a formcontrol for checkbox as follows

```
 this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  locationFormGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
    title: ['', Validators.required],
    description: ['', Validators.required],
    address: ['', Validators.required],
    city: ['', Validators.required],
    province: ['', Validators.required],
    postalCode: ['', Validators.required],
    hideAddress: [''],
    hideCompany: ['']
  })
});
```

and template as follows

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="card card-body">
          <div class="checkbox c-checkbox">
              <h4>
                  <input class="form-control" formControlName="hideCompany" name="hideCompany"  type="checkbox" checked="" />
                  <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Hide Company Name
              </h4>

          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Noticing the weird behaviour, checkbox is NOT clickable but click on the name check/uncheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the name to be clickable and control the checkbox you'll need to wrap it in a label tag and give the checkbox an id

`<input id="hideCompany">`
`<label for="hideCompany">Hide Company Name</label>`

see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1djrxi
click on checkbox or label works

p.s.: are you initializing `myForm` in the ngOnInit or constructor ? If yes, there is no need. You can just do it in the component itself, see my example.

p.p.s: don't forget to wrap your form in the formGroup directive.